# How to restore it in case of accidental termination of one of the processes in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, join, multiprocessing

Good day everyone!

I'm trying to create a simulation (private task) of accidentally terminating a process in multiprocessing and recovering it.

I created 2 identical functions that run in different processes.
Created a function that randomly selects one of the processes and terminates it.
Created a function that monitors running processes and, if it does not find the desired process, starts it again.

The problem is that when you start the process again, you need to execute join (). But if I execute a join from a function that restores the process, then it starts waiting for its completion. Those. if another process is terminated at this time, the recovery will not start.

What is the right way to do something like this?

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import psutil
import os

def proc_1(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_1: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_1 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def proc_2(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_2: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_2 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def process_killer(PID_list, timepass, exclusion_list=[]):
    while True:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        time.sleep(x)
        this_process_pid = os.getpid()
        this_process = psutil.Process(this_process_pid)
        this_process_info_as_dict = this_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_pid = this_process.ppid()
        parent_process = psutil.Process(parent_process_pid)
        parent_process_as_dict = parent_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_children = parent_process.children(recursive=True)
        child_pid_list = []
        for i in range(len(parent_process_children)):
            child_info_as_dict = parent_process_children[i].as_dict()
            if child_info_as_dict['pid'] != this_process_pid:
                child_pid_list.append(child_info_as_dict['pid'])
        child_pid_list = list(set(child_pid_list) - set(exclusion_list))
        # for i in range(len(child_pid_list)):
        #     print(f'Process_{i+1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}')
        print('\n'.join([f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}' for i in range(len(child_pid_list))]))

        if len(child_pid_list) > 0:
            if len(child_pid_list) > 1:
                number = random.randint(0, len(child_pid_list) - 1)
            else:
                number = 0
            kill_proc = psutil.Process(child_pid_list[number])
            kill_process_info_as_dict = kill_proc.as_dict()
            if psutil.pid_exists(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']):
                if kill_process_info_as_dict['name'] == "python.exe":
                    print("We kill the process with PID", kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    try:
                        kill_proc.kill()
                        print(f"Process with PID {kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']} killed.")
                        child_pid_list.remove(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                        print(f"Process with PID {child_pid_list[number]} not found.")


def process_recovery(process_pid_list):
    while True:
        for i in range(len(process_pid_list)):
            if psutil.pid_exists(process_pid_list[i]):
                pass
                # print(f'Process with PID {process_pid} is alive')
            else:
                print(f'Process with PID {process_pid_list[0]} is dead')
                print(f'Restoring the process')
                if process_pid_list[i] == process_pid_list[0]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
                if process_pid_list[i] == process_pid_list[1]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})
                process.start()
                process_pid_list[i] = process.pid
                temp_str = '\n'.join(
                    [f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {process_pid_list[i]}' for i in range(len(process_pid_list))])
                print('Recovery result:\n' + temp_str)
                process.join()

        time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_name_list = ["process_1", "process_2"]

    process_1 = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
    process_2 = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})

    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()

    PID_list = [process_1.pid, process_2.pid]

    process_recov = mp.Process(target=process_recovery, kwargs={'process_pid_list': PID_list})
    process_recov.start()

    process_kill = mp.Process(target=process_killer,
                              kwargs={'PID_list': PID_list, 'timepass': 10, 'exclusion_list': [process_recov.pid, ]})
    process_kill.start()

    print("Main PID:", os.getpid())
    print("Process_1 PID:", process_1.pid)
    print("Process_2 PID:", process_2.pid)
    print("Process_killer PID:", process_kill.pid)

    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
    process_kill.join()
    process_recov.join()

    time.sleep(5)

    print("Program completed")
```

I tried to find information on a specific topic but couldn't implement my problem.

P.S. In fact, the problem is solved if we refuse to use the function called process_recov and make an infinite loop inside the main process by analogy. However, this option fails for me.
But I will publish it too, so that it is useful to someone.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import psutil
import os

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
def proc_1(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_1: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_1 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def proc_2(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_2: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_2 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def process_killer(PID_list, timepass, exclusion_list=[]):
    while True:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        time.sleep(x)
        this_process_pid = os.getpid()
        this_process = psutil.Process(this_process_pid)
        this_process_info_as_dict = this_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_pid = this_process.ppid()
        parent_process = psutil.Process(parent_process_pid)
        parent_process_as_dict = parent_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_children = parent_process.children(recursive=True)
        child_pid_list = []
        for i in range(len(parent_process_children)):
            child_info_as_dict = parent_process_children[i].as_dict()
            if child_info_as_dict['pid'] != this_process_pid:
                child_pid_list.append(child_info_as_dict['pid'])
        child_pid_list = list(set(child_pid_list) - set(exclusion_list))
        child_pid_list = list(set(child_pid_list) - set([this_process_pid]))
        # for i in range(len(child_pid_list)):
        #     print(f'Process_{i+1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}')
        temp_str = '\n'.join([f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}' for i in range(len(child_pid_list))])
        print(f"{temp_str}")

        if len(child_pid_list) > 0:
            if len(child_pid_list) > 1:
                number = random.randint(0, len(child_pid_list) - 1)
            else:
                number = 0
            kill_proc = psutil.Process(child_pid_list[number])
            kill_process_info_as_dict = kill_proc.as_dict()
            if psutil.pid_exists(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']):
                if kill_process_info_as_dict['name'] == "python.exe":
                    print("We kill the process with PID", kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    try:
                        process = psutil.Process(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                        print(f"Process with PID {child_pid_list[number]} not found.")
                        continue
                    else:
                        kill_proc.kill()
                        print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}Process with PID {kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']} killed.{bcolors.ENDC}")
                        child_pid_list.remove(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])


def process_recovery(process_pid_list):
    while True:
        for i in range(len(process_pid_list)):
            if psutil.pid_exists(process_pid_list[i]):
                pass
                # print(f'Process with PID {process_pid} is alive')
            else:
                print(f'Process with PID {process_pid_list[0]} is dead')
                print(f'Restoring the process')
                if process_pid_list[i] == process_pid_list[0]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
                if process_pid_list[i] == process_pid_list[1]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})
                process.start()
                process_pid_list[i] = process.pid
                temp_str = '\n'.join(
                    [f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {process_pid_list[i]}' for i in range(len(process_pid_list))])
                print('Recovery result:\n' + temp_str)
                process.join()

        time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_name_list = ["process_1", "process_2"]

    process_1 = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
    process_2 = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})

    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()

    PID_list = [process_1.pid, process_2.pid]

    # process_recov = mp.Process(target=process_recovery, kwargs={'process_pid_list': PID_list})
    # process_recov.start()

    process_kill = mp.Process(target=process_killer,
                              kwargs={'PID_list': PID_list, 'timepass': 10, 'exclusion_list': []})
    process_kill.start()

    PID_list.append(process_kill.pid)

    while True:
        for i in range(len(PID_list)):
            if psutil.pid_exists(PID_list[i]):
                pass
                # print(f'Process with PID {process_pid} is alive')
            else:
                print(f'Process with PID {PID_list[0]} is dead')
                print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Restoring the process{bcolors.ENDC}")
                if PID_list[i] == PID_list[0]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
                if PID_list[i] == PID_list[1]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})
                process.start()
                old_pid = PID_list[i]
                PID_list[i] = process.pid

                temp_str=""
                for i in range(len(PID_list)):
                    if  PID_list[i]==process.pid:
                        temp_str += f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Process_{i + 1} PID: {PID_list[i]}{bcolors.ENDC} (old: {old_pid})\n'
                    else:
                        temp_str += f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {PID_list[i]}\n'
                temp_str = temp_str.rstrip()
                # temp_str = '\n'.join(
                #     [f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {PID_list[i]}' for i in range(len(PID_list))])
                print('Recovery result:\n' + temp_str)
        time.sleep(0.2)





    print("Main PID:", os.getpid())
    print("Process_1 PID:", process_1.pid)
    print("Process_2 PID:", process_2.pid)
    print("Process_killer PID:", process_kill.pid)

    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
    process_kill.join()
    # process_recov.join()
    process.join()

    time.sleep(5)

    print("Program completed")
```

Comment: Why do you have to join the newly created process?

Comment: Since I'm doing a simulation, I need to say about the root cause! In my real program, as part of one of the functions that runs in a separate process, it renders the page, which uses the background process of the browser. If you do not do join, then for some reason this process is incorrectly completed. The browser does not close and the number of its processes in the system starts to grow.

Comment: You could try to create a separate thread just to execute the `process.join`.

Comment: A thread instead of a process will not suit me. The reason is the same. HTML render does not work within a thread. Those. for my real program, this execution is not suitable. Or did I misunderstand you? Maybe you can show an example of the implementation of what you are talking about?

Comment: I meant to replace `process.join()` with something like `threading.Thread(target=process.join).start()`.

Comment: Still don't quite understand where and how to do it? Can you change my code or be more specific please!

Comment: The line is near the end of the `process_recovery` function.

Comment: I applied your suggestion with `threading.Thread(target=process.join).start()`. And it seems to me that everything works. But I can't figure out what I did this line? Could you give a detailed comment?

Comment: It creates and starts a separate thread which only executes `process.join()` and ends then. Therefore the main thread isn't blocked but the `join` is executed.

Comment: I understand correctly that in the process_recovery process, a certain parallel thread arises that is waiting for completion, which allows you to "release" the process_recovery itself?

Comment: Exactly. The job to wait for the process to end and `join` it is transferred to the new thread while main thread can continue to do other important things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of the code based on the `threading.Thread(target=process.join).start()` example with some modifications.

```
# Работа с процессами - рабочая, но сомнительная версия
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import time
import random
import psutil
import os

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

def proc_1(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_1: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_1 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def proc_2(timepass=1, repeat=20):
    repeated = True
    i = 0
    while repeated:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        i += 1
        if i < repeat:
            print("Proc_2: " + str(i) + ", will fall asleep for: " + str(x))
        else:
            repeated = False
            print("Proc_2 COMPLETED!")
            break
        time.sleep(x)


def process_killer(PID_list, timepass, exclusion_list=[]):
    while True:
        x = random.uniform(0, timepass)
        time.sleep(x)
        this_process_pid = os.getpid()
        this_process = psutil.Process(this_process_pid)
        this_process_info_as_dict = this_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_pid = this_process.ppid()
        parent_process = psutil.Process(parent_process_pid)
        parent_process_as_dict = parent_process.as_dict()
        parent_process_children = parent_process.children(recursive=True)
        child_pid_list = []
        for i in range(len(parent_process_children)):
            child_info_as_dict = parent_process_children[i].as_dict()
            if child_info_as_dict['pid'] != this_process_pid:
                child_pid_list.append(child_info_as_dict['pid'])
        child_pid_list = list(set(child_pid_list) - set(exclusion_list))
        # for i in range(len(child_pid_list)):
        #     print(f'Process_{i+1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}')
        temp_str = '\n'.join([f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}' for i in range(len(child_pid_list))])
        print(f"{temp_str}")

        if len(child_pid_list) > 0:
            if len(child_pid_list) > 1:
                number = random.randint(0, len(child_pid_list) - 1)
            else:
                number = 0
            kill_proc = psutil.Process(child_pid_list[number])
            kill_process_info_as_dict = kill_proc.as_dict()
            if psutil.pid_exists(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']):
                if kill_process_info_as_dict['name'] == "python.exe":
                    print("We kill the process with PID", kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    try:
                        process = psutil.Process(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])
                    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                        print(f"Process with PID {child_pid_list[number]} not found.")
                        continue
                    else:
                        kill_proc.kill()
                        print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}Process with PID {kill_process_info_as_dict['pid']} killed.{bcolors.ENDC}")
                        child_pid_list.remove(kill_process_info_as_dict['pid'])


def process_recovery(process_pid_list):
    PID_list = process_pid_list
    this_process_pid = os.getpid()
    this_process = psutil.Process(this_process_pid)
    this_process_info_as_dict = this_process.as_dict()
    parent_process_pid = this_process.ppid()
    parent_process = psutil.Process(parent_process_pid)
    parent_process_as_dict = parent_process.as_dict()
    parent_process_children = parent_process.children(recursive=True)
    child_pid_list = []
    for i in range(len(parent_process_children)):
        child_info_as_dict = parent_process_children[i].as_dict()
        if child_info_as_dict['pid'] != this_process_pid:
            child_pid_list.append(child_info_as_dict['pid'])

    while True:
        for i in range(len(child_pid_list)):
            if psutil.pid_exists(child_pid_list[i]):
                pass
                # print(f'Process with PID {process_pid} is alive')
            else:
                print(f'Process with PID {child_pid_list[i]} is dead')
                print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Restoring the process{bcolors.ENDC}")
                if child_pid_list[i] == PID_list[0]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
                elif child_pid_list[i] == PID_list[1]:
                    process = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})
                else:
                    process = mp.Process(target=process_killer,
                                              kwargs={'PID_list': PID_list, 'timepass': 10,
                                                      'exclusion_list': [process_recov.pid, ]})
                process.start()
                old_pid = child_pid_list[i]
                child_pid_list[i] = process.pid
                if old_pid == PID_list[0]:
                    PID_list[0] = process.pid
                if old_pid == PID_list[1]:
                    PID_list[1] = process.pid

                temp_str = ""
                for i in range(len(child_pid_list)):
                    if child_pid_list[i] == process.pid:
                        temp_str += f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Process_{i + 1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}{bcolors.ENDC} (old: {old_pid})\n'
                    else:
                        temp_str += f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {child_pid_list[i]}\n'
                temp_str = temp_str.rstrip()
                # temp_str = '\n'.join(
                #     [f'Process_{i + 1} PID: {PID_list[i]}' for i in range(len(PID_list))])
                print('Recovery result:\n' + temp_str)
                threading.Thread(target=process.join).start()

        time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_name_list = ["process_1", "process_2"]

    process_1 = mp.Process(target=proc_1, kwargs={'timepass': 2, 'repeat': 30})
    process_2 = mp.Process(target=proc_2, kwargs={'timepass': 3, 'repeat': 30})

    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()

    PID_list = [process_1.pid, process_2.pid]

    process_recov = mp.Process(target=process_recovery, kwargs={'process_pid_list': PID_list})
    process_recov.start()

    process_kill = mp.Process(target=process_killer,
                              kwargs={'PID_list': PID_list, 'timepass': 10, 'exclusion_list': [process_recov.pid, ]})
    process_kill.start()



    print("Main PID:", os.getpid())
    print("Process_1 PID:", process_1.pid)
    print("Process_2 PID:", process_2.pid)
    print("Process_killer PID:", process_kill.pid)

    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
    process_kill.join()
    process_recov.join()

    time.sleep(5)

    print("Program completed")
```